# why the value changing element remains constant while taking the data from axios?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

this code of js has written in vue.js framework. I have taken some links **(webURL)** from which I want to take the file in my project and taken some other data elements also. The update details function updates the selectedState variable when I hover mouse on a particular state. The output shows a country map and a state of the country of webURL[0]. In the console box the value is also updating.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    webURL:[{
      id:0,URL:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/districts/Andhra%20Pradesh.json?token=AOYHVJ22Y4JWLLUXWXODLRK6ZKARK"
    },
  {
    id:22,URL:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/districts/rajasthan.json?token=AOYHVJ575LRB2FOYBJMVKWK6ZKAVY"
  },
  {
    id:3,URL:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/states.json?token=AOYHVJ2BNIP7L3TMOE66JWK6ZKBRK"
  }
],
    selectedState:0,
    cityJson: null,
    statesJson: null
  },
  methods:{
    updateDetails:function(index, evt)
    {
      this.selectedState = index
    //  return this.statesJson.features[this.selectedState].id
      console.log(this.selectedState)
      console.log(this.statesJson.features[this.selectedState].id)
    }
  },
```

This created function takes the input from the links through axios. But the data element **selectedState** is unable to update in the created function. However it is updating in above code.

```
  created () {
    axios.all([axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/states.json?token=AOYHVJ2BNIP7L3TMOE66JWK6ZKBRK'),
               axios.get(this.webURL[this.selectedState].URL)])
      .then(axios.spread((user1,user2) => (
        console.log(user1.data),
        console.log(this.selectedState),
        console.log(user2.data),
        this.statesJson=user1.data,
        this.cityJson=user2.data
//      this.statesJson = response.data,
  //  console.log(response))
)))
      .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  },
```

This is the code in d3 library helps to plot the path.

```
  computed: {
    // Typical projection for showing all states scaled and positioned appropriately
    projection () {
      return d3.geoMercator().scale(900).translate([-700, 700])
    },

    // Function for converting GPS coordinates into path coordinates
    pathGenerator () {
      return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection)
    },
    projection1 () {
      return d3.geoMercator().scale(2500).translate([-2300, 1000])
    },

    // Function for converting GPS coordinates into path coordinates
    pathGenerator1 () {
      return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection1)
    },


    // Combine the states GeoJSON with a rank-based gradient
    stateData () {
      return this.statesJson ? this.statesJson.features.map(feature => {
        //let state = this.happiestStates.find(state => state.state === feature.id)
        return {
          feature,
          color: this.stateColor(feature.rank)
        }
      }):[]
    },
    cityData(){
      return this.cityJson ? this.cityJson.features.map(feature1 =>{
        return {
          feature1
        }
      }):[]
    },
    // Interpolate from red to green in the domain 50 to 1 (our ranking)
    stateColor () {
      return d3.scaleSequential().domain([50, 1]).interpolator(d3.interpolateRdYlGn)
    }
  },

})
```

In this HTML code first path tag is used to plot the country map and second is used to plot the state map. State map should be shown separately when hovering mouse on that state but **selectedState=0** map is showing only.

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="tooltip" display="none" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
  <svg id="svg" ref="svg" height="800" width="1600">
   <path class="bar"
     v-for="(state, index) in stateData"
     :d="pathGenerator(state.feature)"
     :style="{
       fill: state.color,
       stroke: 'darkslategray'
     }"
      @mouseover="updateDetails(index,state)"
      @mouseover = "cityCreated()"
      @mouseout = "hideTooltip()"
      >
   </path>
     <path class="bar"
       v-for="(city, index) in cityData"
       :d="pathGenerator1(city.feature1)"
       :style="{
         fill: city.color,
         stroke: 'darkslategray'
       }">
     </path>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 events of the same type on the same element? consider replacing it with one and calling the other from within one

Comment: can you please tell me in more detail?

Comment: events in vue.js are treated as attributes and you can't have duplicate attributes. So you need to remove one `mouseover` event and then call the other one from within from within the one that is still in place. So for example you call the `cityCreated()` from within the `updateDetails(index,state)`. The way it is now, they both don't get called and as such you can't see the updates you are expecting.

Comment: actually there is no funtion ```cityCreated()``` in my code. It just remain there in the trial of my code. I have removed it now. The main problem is that in ```created()``` function the ```this.selectedState``` is not changing it's value although it is changing its value in the ```updateDetails()``` function. The value of this is changing according to the index number.

Comment: Is there any line in the `created` function where you are changing it? I can't find any

Comment: ummmm.......No. Can you please tell me how to do that?